# Why do Javascript minifiers convert === to ==?

Tags: javascript, minify

Looking between the very first line of code in Bootstrap's minified and unminified JS file, there is an immediate discrepancy:

```
// bootstrap.js
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') { ... }
```

vs.

```
// bootstrap.min.js
if("undefined"==typeof jQuery)...
```

(See for yourself: [bootstrap.js](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.js) and [bootstrap.min.js](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js))

I'm confused why this is allowed.  My (perhaps naïve) understanding is that `===` is always a performance gain, and often prevents unexpected results (falsy comparisons with 0 or `""`, for example).  It would seem that the small gains in filesize are lost in performance and potential for erroneous result.  Can anyone shed light here?

Comment: `typeof` always returns a string, so `===` is unnecessary. The minifier or some other processor the file was run through could have recognized this. There's no potential for an incorrect result, and even if this line were to run often enough to be a bottleneck, any performance difference would be JITted away.

Comment: Everyone is answering without fully understanding the question.

Comment: @NickDugger that is not true; the question is quite clear. The performance advantage of `===` is only relevant when the operands aren't of the same type.

Comment: Does it convert _all_ instances, or merely the type-safe instances?

Comment: @NickDugger What are people missing? It's usually better to provide details with what the error is, or provide your own answer that's more correct.

Comment: This is shameful, but the real issue was that I was not reading the answers clearly enough... my bad!

Comment: Live and learn, Mr. Dugger :)

Comment: This is JavaScript, you can replace anything with anything and it still almost works. (Sorry, couldn't help myself.)

Comment: when used with typeof, "==" is faster executing than "===", always produces the same result, and takes up 
fewer bytes of code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the particular code you're citing, it's safe because the types of both operands are invariant, and both are strings. There's no performance savings possible because there'll never need to be any type coercion. Think of `==` as being  something like this:

```
function ==(a, b) { // obviously this is fake
  if (a === b) return true;
  // type coercion ...
}
```

Also, personally I think that one should use `===` over `==` because of the *semantic* differences and not because of performance. Micro-optimizations like that aren't important for the vast majority of code most people write. <strike>(It's a little ironic in fact that the check for the presence of jQuery is being done with a `typeof` comparison; that itself is a questionably-valuable micro-optimization.)</strike> oops that was wrong :)

Comment: Nice answer!  Just wanted to clarify for anyone else who may have had trouble reading the pseudo-code that `// type coercion` is the _de facto_ `else`, not a description of what's happening above.

Comment: @Impirator oh yes, good point. I wrote it like that to emphasize that the work is finished if the values are equal under the rules of `===` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` will always return a string, so there is no need to worry about type conversion. Ultimately, this doesn't really save much in the file or its execution, but this is considered a safe assumption.